# Armstrong Number C++

Tags: c++, loops

**How to ask the user if want continue ?**

```
while(y != 0)
{
    d=y%10;
    z=z+(d*d*d);
    y=y/10;
}
```

if true or false :

```
switch ( z == x )
{
case true :cout <<x <<" is an Armstrong Number" << endl;
break ;
case false :cout <<x << " is not an Armstrong Number"<<endl;
}
```

The output like this :

> Please enter a number to check if it is an Armstrong number: 371 
> 371
>   is an Armstrong Number 
> Do you want to continue (Y/N) ? N
>  Bye!

if write 'Y' it will be continue in the same question.

I work :

```
while (y != 0)
{
    d=y%10;
    z=z+(d*d*d);
    y=y/10;
}
if ( z == x )
{
 cout <<x <<" is an Armstrong Number" << endl;
}
if ( z != x )
{
cout <<x << " is not an Armstrong Number"<<endl;
}

cout << "Do you want to continue (Y/N) ? " ;
    cin >> m;
    do{
    cout <<"Please enter a number to check if it is an Armstrong number:";
cin >> x;
    if ( z == x )
{
 cout <<x <<" is an Armstrong Number" << endl;
}
if ( z != x )
{
cout <<x << " is not an Armstrong Number"<<endl;
}
cout << "Do you want to continue (Y/N) ? " ;
    cin >> m;
    }while ( m == 'Y' || m == 'y') ;

 cout << "Bye"<<endl;
```

but it's wrong !

Comment: you can encapsulate the whole thing in another while loop and after you `switch`, if the input is `n`, then break;

Comment: i've never seen a `switch/case` shoehorned into something that should be an `if/else` worse than this

Comment: you mean like this : if ( z == x )
 cout <<x <<" is an Armstrong Number" << endl;
else
cout <<x << " is not an Armstrong Number"<<endl;

Comment: @Lablabla I did it but it's not run correct!

Answer (score 0):

After you have declared your variables start the do-while loop:`do{`. After the part which asks the user whether he wants to continue or not close it like this `}while(ans == 'Y');` where 'ans' is the char variable which stores the users answer (Y/N). Like this:

```
        //Here are the declared variables.
   do{
      cout << "Please enter a number to check if it is an Armstrong number: ";
      cin >> number; //Replace 'number' with the variable name you have used to store that number.
      //The algorithm, which tests if the number is Armstrong number or not, goes here.
      cout << "Do you want to continue (Y/N)? ";
      cin >> ans;
      }while(ans == 'Y');
      cout << "Bye";
```

Comment: From 'while(y != 0)' till 'cout <<x << " is not an Armstrong Number"<<endl;
}' goes at the line where I commented '//The algorithm, which tests..., goes here.'